# More than one input file in this Python code

Tags: python, input

I am using this code for searching a target_string in a single input file (input.txt) and "extracting" those lines with the target_string in an output file (output.txt). Now I want to perform the same procedure but with several input files, for instance, input1.txt, input2.txt, input3.txt, ...

How can I modify this code for doing this?

```
from collections import deque
input_file = 'input.txt'
output_file = 'output.txt'
buscado = 'target_string'
 contexto = deque([], 4)
    
   
 for line in f_in:
    with open(input_file) as f_in, open(output_file, "w") as f_out: 
     contexto.append(line)
         if  len(contexto) < 4:
           continue
         if buscado in contexto[1]:
           f_out.writelines(contexto)
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list with the filenames, such as:

```
file_list = ['file-1.txt', 'file-2.txt', ...]
```

for each of the filenames you can then run your existing code:

```
for file in file_list:
    # open file
    # loop through lines
    ...
```

Comment: I tryed to add these line in the code and it's not running. I'm not a proffesional coder, can you help me showing how should I add this part of the code into mine, please?

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import deque
output_file = 'output.txt'
buscado = 'target_string'
contexto = deque([], 4)
file_list = ['input1.txt', 'input2.txt', 'input3.txt']


def myfun(input_file):
    for line in f_in:
        with open(input_file) as f_in, open(output_file, "w") as f_out: 
            contexto.append(line)
        if  len(contexto) < 4:
            continue
        if buscado in contexto[1]:
            f_out.writelines(contexto)

for file in file_list:
    myfun(file)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand this code. It totally changed my code and I don't know where to set my target_string

Comment: Combine two answers

Comment: how? I can't understand your answers